# histogram of grouped/count/ data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have aggregated data with each line representing several individuals, like

```
data <- tribble(
  ~x, ~count,
  10, 2,
  12, 5, 
  10, 1, 
  15, 12,
  15.5, 2,
  11, 7,
  19, 1,
  14, 1,
  9, 1,
  17, 1,
  13, 4)
```

Is it possible to create a histogram or a density plot suing counts

```
data %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, count = count)) + geom_histogram(bins = 5)
```

(in this case count is ignored), or should I ungroup the data?

Answer (score 0):

I think `geom_col` is a better fit for this than `geom_histogram`, though it is possible to use `geom_histogram(stat = "identity")` (as in a previous version of this answer.)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
data <- tribble(
    ~x, ~count,
    10, 2,
    12, 5, 
    10, 1, 
    15, 12,
    15.5, 2,
    11, 7,
    19, 1,
    14, 1,
    9, 1,
    17, 1,
    13, 4) 
data %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = count)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: this did not work at all for a large dataset,, but ungrouping seems to be a solution:
 
`data %>% uncount(count) %>% ggplot(aes(x = x)) +  geom_histogram()`

Comment: What does "did not work at all" mean? An error, or output not as you would expect?

Comment: Sorry, was not clear. with 2k records dataset, it does not produce any output (empty plot). 

Here is example with 50 records. Using proposed approach it produces some output, but this is not what I would like. 

`data1 <-fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/giwwep7ij6t4er2/testdata50.csv?dl=1")`

approach 1: 
`data1 %>%  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = count)) + geom_col()`

approach 2: `data1 %>%  uncount(count) %>% ggplot(aes(x = x)) +  geom_histogram(bins=10)`